# Accessing functions or variables in an IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

I have created some JavaScript that I would like to wrap in an IIFE, but I'm finding it difficult, as the JavaScript contains variables and functions that are used in different JS files.

Example:

**my-app.js**

```
(function(window, document, $){

    var currentArea;

    function changeAreaTo(value){
        currentArea = $('.sp-spine-item:eq('+value+')');
    }

}(window, document, window.jQuery));
```

**outside-app.js**

```
(function(window, document, $){

    changeAreaTo(3);
    $('html, body').scrollTop(currentArea.position().top);

}(window, document, window.jQuery));
```

My actual JS is a bit more complicated than above, but this gives you a basic idea of what I'm dealing with.

my-app.js is something that might be used across multiple projects, but shouldn't be modified for each of those projects, it's kind of like a base library.

So, I'm wondering what is the best way for outside JS files to get access to any variable or function in a separate IIFE.

Comment: look at the revealing module pattern

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is return the function that you want accessible in another file, and assign it to something that is globally accessible.

```
var changeAreaTo = (function(window, document, $){

    var currentArea;

    function changeAreaTo(value){
        currentArea = $('.sp-spine-item:eq('+value+')');
    }
    return changeAreaTo;

}(window, document, window.jQuery));
```